# Finding Station order number along way using PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, knn

In QGIS and PostGIS I have two layers:

- way (id, name, geom (multistring))
- station (id, name, geom (polygon))

How do I find the station order along each way?

[image]

I tried using code of [Finding all intersections of LineString and Polygon and order in which it intersects it using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179061)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as id, station.nome as station, dp.path, dp.way_name, station.geom FROM s_602_ptrc.station, (
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path[2] as path,
       (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom as geom, 
       way.name as way_name from s_602_ptrc.way
) as dp 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(dp.geom, station.geom) 
ORDER BY dp.way_name, dp.path;
```

with this result.

[image]

Only the stations that are nodes of the polyline are considered - But how to consider them all?

**UPDATE**

the first part of the code of @Geozelot goes all null values ​​for the way_part:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query assumes that there is **a vertex of your lines intersecting every polygon**, but that seems not to be the case, and is a rather ineffective methodology at best; you'd need to `ST_Segmentize` your lines with a rather smallish `max_segment_length`, which effectively increases the vertex count of your *LineStrings*, to increase the chance that every polygon intersects a vertice.
However, you'd then also have to e.g. `DISTINCT ON (station.id)` to not count multiple intersections per polygon.

But what if a polygon happens to intersect vertices of two or more lines? Or none at all, as in your case here? A plain intersection predicate may very well be highly ambiguous (note that you will always have a certain ambiguity, but you can limit it to edge cases only).

---

First off, having circle *Polygons* for stations is likely a bad choice, at least in terms of network topology. I suggest to **work with points**, either the original points if available, or the *Polygon* centroids.

The same goes for *MultiLineStrings*; you will almost always **have to dump them** to work with them properly. And especially for large tables, the spatial indexes are much more effective (while dumping them on-the-fly will leave them having no index at all).

I would then find the nearest *LineString* to each station *Point*, and order the result by the fraction of line length of the shortest distance projection of each *Point* on that line. The two main tools are a `LATERAL` *(K)NN* subquery, and `ST_LineLocatePoint`.

I will use `ST_Centroid` on the *Polygons*, but a CTE to create the dumped *LineStrings*; note that these (within a CTE) **will have no spatial index**, and performance will suffer; I'd suggest to at least dump *them* into a table and index them properly:

```
WITH
  dumped_ways AS (
    SELECT "name",
           dmp.path[1] AS way_part,
           dmp.geom
    FROM   s_602_ptrc.way,
           LATERAL ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
  )

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nway."name", nway.way_part ORDER BY nway._frac) AS station_id,
       station.nome AS station,
       nway."name",
       nway.way_part,
       station.geom
FROM   s_602_ptrc.station AS station
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT dumped_ways."name",
         dumped_ways.way_part,
         ST_LineLocatePoint(dumped_ways.geom, ST_Centroid(station.geom)) AS _frac
  FROM   dumped_ways
  ORDER BY
         dumped_ways.geom <-> ST_Centroid(station.geom)
  LIMIT  1
) AS nway
ORDER BY
       nway."name",
       nway.way_part,
       nway._frac
;
```

**Update:**

Since you followed my suggestion to dump your *MultiLineStrings* into a table of simple *LineStrings*, there's no need for either the CTE, or any reference to `way_part`.

Just run:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nway."name" ORDER BY nway._frac) AS station_id,
       station.nome AS station,
       nway."name",
       station.geom
FROM   s_602_ptrc.station
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT way."name",
         ST_LineLocatePoint(way.geom, ST_Centroid(station.geom)) AS _frac
  FROM   s_602_ptrc.way AS way
  ORDER BY
         way.geom <-> ST_Centroid(station.geom)
  LIMIT  1
) AS nway
ORDER BY
       nway."name",
       nway._frac
;
```

This will find the nearest `way.geom` to every `ST_Centroid(station.geom)`, calculate the fraction along the found line at which the given centroid can be projected on at shortest distance, and create an `id` in `ORDER BY` that fraction.

Note that

- this may yield wrong results in edge cases like intersections, where the closest edge to a centroid is semantically not the correct one
- the `station_id` increases in line direction, from `ST_StartPoint` to `ST_EndPoint`

Comment: I wrote this from the top of my head, let me know if there are any typos etc., or any syntax correction needed.

Comment: Thanks @Geozelot. way is a linestring now.

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: @DanielePiccolo if `dmp.path` (-> `way_part`) is an empty array (`NULL`), you're not passing *Multi* geometries to `ST_Dump`; you don't need the CTE if you are using simple geometries in a table, and you can remove every reference to `way_part` from the query.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo see my update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @geozelot. Now I can't try your code. Maybe ,in st_linelocatepoint, I must insert st_centroid(station.geom). 
it seems to me that the function needs a point geometry., Isn't It?

Comment: @DanielePiccolo ,) you're right...I haven't debugged that query, just wrote it down. I updated the answer again.

Comment: I think it's right. This afternoon I Will tell you

Comment: I updated the code of your answer by correcting some errors on the column names and adding an id. Now It works. thanks for your willingness to help me.